# AWS Amplify Gen 2 build fails with GLIBC version error for Next.js 14 App

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, next.js14

I'm deploying a Next.js 14 application using AWS Amplify Gen 2, but my build fails with a GLIBC version error. The error messages suggest that the required versions of GLIBC (`GLIBC_2.27` and `GLIBC_2.28`) are not found. I'm using the Amazon Linux 2023 build image (`amplify:al2023`).

Here are the relevant error messages from the build log:

```
2024-01-31T11:03:13.753Z [INFO]: # Executing command: nvm use 20

2024-01-31T11:03:14.232Z [INFO]: Now using node v20.11.0 (npm v)

2024-01-31T11:03:14.232Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm ci

2024-01-31T11:03:14.234Z [WARNING]: node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)

node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

2024-01-31T11:03:14.235Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed

2024-01-31T11:03:14.236Z [INFO]: Please read more about Amplify Hosting's support for SSR frameworks to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-ssr-framework-support.html. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html

2024-01-31T11:03:14.236Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1

2024-01-31T11:03:14.236Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...

2024-01-31T11:03:14.236Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

I'm not understanding the problem since I'm already using Amazon Linux 2023. Here is my `amplify.yml`:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - nvm install 20
        - nvm use 20
        - npm ci
        - npx amplify pipeline-deploy --branch $AWS_BRANCH --app-id $AWS_APP_ID
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
image:
 buildImage: 'amplify:al2023'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just putting the environment variable `_CUSTOM_IMAGE` with `amplify:al2023` value.